# Why does Spring boot takes really long time to start when Xmx == Xms?

Tags: java, memory-management, spring-boot, parameters, jvm

I have set `Xms2400m` and `Xmx3600m` in my Eclipse. But when I run my Spring boot application with both Xms and Xmx set to 2400m it takes really long time to start.

Can anyone explain why does it slow down the initialization of Spring boot application when the Initial memory and the Maximum allocated memory to JVM are same?

Just to let you know when I created the spring boot application values were `Xms2400m` and `Xmx3600m`. But when Xmx was changed to 2400m time taken to start the application became really slow.

Comment: So what happens if you set both to `3600m`?

Comment: you could try `jvisualvm` to analyze.

Comment: My guess is that the heap is too small.

Comment: I think you are jumping to conclusions too quickly here.

Comment: @dunni its the same.